# How to grep on multiple pattern with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, findstr

I have the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\zorg> Get-Acl HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv | Format-List * 


PSPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
PSParentPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
PSChildName             : wuauserv
PSDrive                 : HKLM
PSProvider              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
CentralAccessPolicyId   : 
CentralAccessPolicyName : 
Path                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
Owner                   : AUTORITE NT\Système
Group                   : AUTORITE NT\Système
---snipped---
AccessToString          : DESKTOP-MAU75IM\zorg Allow  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Utilisateurs Allow  ReadKey
                          BUILTIN\Utilisateurs Allow  -2147483648
                          BUILTIN\Administrateurs Allow  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Administrateurs Allow  268435456
                          AUTORITE NT\Système Allow  FullControl
                          AUTORITE NT\Système Allow  268435456
                          CREATEUR PROPRIETAIRE Allow  268435456
                          AUTORITÉ DE PACKAGE D’APPLICATION\TOUS LES PACKAGES D’APPLICATION Allow  ReadKey
---snipped---
AccessRightType         : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights
AccessRuleType          : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule
AuditRuleType           : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule
AreAccessRulesProtected : False
AreAuditRulesProtected  : False
AreAccessRulesCanonical : True
AreAuditRulesCanonical  : True
```

And i would like to output only the `PSPath` object and the `AccessToString` object where the latter is equals to `zorg`.

How could i do that? (oneliner preferred)

Comment: So you should use `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` instead of `Format-List`.

Comment: Powershell 101.

Comment: 'How could i do that? (oneliner preferred)' Why, as long as you can get the results? Sure, you can, but just because you can does not mean you should or that it would be more prudent than a function, etc. As per Olaf, you could also Select-Object and String matching/parsing to get what you want. So, there are multiple ways to get this data. Lots of examples all over the web, on Stackoverflow, videos on Youtube, already that are showing how to handle string/object parsing and in the PowerShell help files.

Answer (score 0):

Never use Format-* until the very last thing. Ensure sure you know you have all your results first, then choose the prudent format style and it may not be Format-* at all. It could be a hash table, custom object, file output, etc.

PowerShell 101 stuff and easy to find examples all over the web and in the help files. Just select the properties you want, not all of them. Well, unless you want all of them

Below are just some ways/ideas to handle this use case, and there are multiple other ways, that could be more elegant.

The fact that you are using the term grep, would indicate you are coming from Linux world (assumption of course, which is fine, many of us do as well), and Linux emits strings, whereas PowerShell emits objects because it's an object-oriented language based on .Net.

```
Clear-Host
Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property PSPath, AccessToString
<#
# Results

PSPath                                                                                            AccessToString                                                    
------                                                                                            --------------                                                    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey... 
#>

Clear-Host
Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property PSPath, AccessToString | 
Format-List
<#
# Results

PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
AccessToString : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
                 APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadKey
                 S-1-15-3-1024-1...Allow  ReadKey
#>

# Grab the property data with a simple select and calulated property, parsing the AccessToString
Clear-Host
Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property PSPath, @{
    Name       = 'AccessToString'
    Expression = {($PSItem.AccessToString -split"`n")[0]}} | 
Format-List
<#
# Results

PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
AccessToString : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
#>

# Extract specific strings using RegEx
Clear-Host
Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property PSPath, @{
    Name       = 'AccesstoString'
    Expression = {[regex]::Matches(($PSItem.AccessToString),'BUILTIN\\Users.*')}
} | 
Format-List
<#
# Results

PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
AccesstoString : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
#>

Clear-Host
Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property PSPath, @{
    Name       = 'AccesstoString'
    Expression = {[regex]::Matches(($PSItem.AccessToString),'^B.*Users.*')}
} | 
Format-List
<#
# Results

PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
AccesstoString : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
#>

Clear-Host
[regex]::Matches($(Out-String -InputObject $(Get-Acl -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv' | 
Select-Object -Property '*') -Width 100),'PSPath.*|AccessToString.*').Value
<#
# Resutlts

PSPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentContr
AccessToString          : BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadKey
#>
```